# Server reloads at same time heroku

Tags: heroku

do you know guys why everyday about the same hour my server hosted on heroku rerun? Mostly it is 22:20 UTC+1. I've tried logging it but nothing really worked. I hope for answer

Comment: Heroku dynos restart frequently, at least once per day. Is that what you're talking about? Why does it matter?

Comment: oh now I know, sorry but my app server was restarting. Thanks